# Переопределение метода c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Вопрос слегка глуповат, но в то же время я не нашел ответа на него.

Мне нужно переопределить метод, который наследуется от `Form` : `DefWndProc`.

Нужен для работы устройства zkt (для авторизации). В данный момент устройство инициализируется полностью в форме для авторизации. Я хотел бы вынести все, касающееся этого устройсва (инициализацию, открытие порта, освобождение данных и т д) в отдельный класс.

> Вопрос : если я перенусу метод `protected override void DefWndProc(ref Message m)` в другой класс, как мне потом переопределить этот же метод, но в классе где я буду инициализировать класс zkt (и все перенесенные методы)

Немного кода как щас (все то, что закоментировано). Это хотелось бы вынести отдельным классом. Что я и сделал (приложения 2) Но как быть с методом переопределения??:

```
public class Authentication : Form
    {

        //IntPtr mDevHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        //IntPtr mDBHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        //IntPtr FormHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        //bool bIsTimeToDie = false;
        //bool IsRegister = false;
        //bool bIdentify = true;
        //byte[] FPBuffer;
        //int RegisterCount = 0;
        //const int REGISTER_FINGER_COUNT = 3;

        //byte[][] RegTmps = new byte[3][];
        //byte[] RegTmp = new byte[2048];
        //byte[] CapTmp = new byte[2048];

        //int cbCapTmp = 2048;
        //int cbRegTmp = 0;
        //int iFid = 1;

        //private int mfpWidth = 0;
        //private int mfpHeight = 0;
        //private int mfpDpi = 0;

        //const int MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK = 0x0400 + 6;

        //[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA")]
        //public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public Authentication()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Authentication_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //FormHandle = this.Handle;
            //this.init();
            //this.open();
            zkt _zkt = new zkt(this.Handle);
            _zkt.init();
            _zkt.open();
            Users us = new Users();
            XmlNodeList users = us.getAllUsers();
            foreach(XmlNode user in users)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(user.SelectSingleNode("login").InnerText);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Users us = new Users();
            try
            {
                if (us.getPasswordByLogin(comboBox1.Text) == maskedTextBox1.Text)
                {
                    Registration reg = new Registration(us.getIdByLogin(comboBox1.Text));
                    reg.Show();
                }
                else MessageBox.Show("Denied");
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid entring");
            }
        }

        #region zkt

        //ComboBox cmbIdx;
        //TextBox textRes;
        //PictureBox picFPImg;
        //TextBox txtTemplate1;
        //TextBox txtTemplate2;

        //private void init()
        //{
        //    cmbIdx = new ComboBox();
        //    cmbIdx.Items.Clear();
        //    int ret = zkfperrdef.ZKFP_ERR_OK;
        //    if ((ret = zkfp2.Init()) == zkfperrdef.ZKFP_ERR_OK)
        //    {
        //        int nCount = zkfp2.GetDeviceCount();
        //        if (nCount > 0)
        //        {
        //            for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++)
        //            {
        //                cmbIdx.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        //            }
        //            cmbIdx.SelectedIndex = 0;
        //            //bnInit.Enabled = false;
        //            //bnFree.Enabled = true;
        //            //bnOpen.Enabled = true;
        //        }
        //        else
        //        {
        //            zkfp2.Terminate();
        //            MessageBox.Show("No device connected!");
        //        }
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        MessageBox.Show("Initialize fail, ret=" + ret + " !");
        //    }
        //}

        //private void free()
        //{
        //    zkfp2.Terminate();
        //    cbRegTmp = 0;
        //    //bnInit.Enabled = true;
        //    //bnFree.Enabled = false;
        //    //bnOpen.Enabled = false;
        //    //bnClose.Enabled = false;
        //    //bnEnroll.Enabled = false;
        //    //bnVerify.Enabled = false;
        //    //bnIdentify.Enabled = false;
        //    //btMatch.Enabled = false;
        //}

        //private void open()
        //{
        //    textRes = new TextBox();
        //    int ret = zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK;
        //    if (IntPtr.Zero == (mDevHandle = zkfp2.OpenDevice(cmbIdx.SelectedIndex)))
        //    {
        //        MessageBox.Show("OpenDevice fail");
        //        return;
        //    }
        //    if (IntPtr.Zero == (mDBHandle = zkfp2.DBInit()))
        //    {
        //        MessageBox.Show("Init DB fail");
        //        zkfp2.CloseDevice(mDevHandle);
        //        mDevHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        //        return;
        //    }
        //    //bnInit.Enabled = false;
        //    //bnFree.Enabled = true;
        //    //bnOpen.Enabled = false;
        //    //bnClose.Enabled = true;
        //    //bnEnroll.Enabled = true;
        //    //bnVerify.Enabled = true;
        //    //bnIdentify.Enabled = true;
        //    //btnOutput.Enabled = true;
        //    //btMatch.Enabled = true;
        //    //btnImport.Enabled = true;
        //    RegisterCount = 0;
        //    cbRegTmp = 0;
        //    iFid = 1;
        //    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        //    {
        //        RegTmps[i] = new byte[2048];
        //    }
        //    byte[] paramValue = new byte[4];
        //    int size = 4;
        //    zkfp2.GetParameters(mDevHandle, 1, paramValue, ref size);
        //    zkfp2.ByteArray2Int(paramValue, ref mfpWidth);

        //    size = 4;
        //    zkfp2.GetParameters(mDevHandle, 2, paramValue, ref size);
        //    zkfp2.ByteArray2Int(paramValue, ref mfpHeight);

        //    FPBuffer = new byte[mfpWidth * mfpHeight];

        //    size = 4;
        //    zkfp2.GetParameters(mDevHandle, 3, paramValue, ref size);
        //    zkfp2.ByteArray2Int(paramValue, ref mfpDpi);

        //    textRes.AppendText("reader parameter, image width:" + mfpWidth + ", height:" + mfpHeight + ", dpi:" + mfpDpi + "\n");

        //    Thread captureThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoCapture));
        //    captureThread.IsBackground = true;
        //    captureThread.Start();
        //    bIsTimeToDie = false;
        //    textRes.AppendText("Open succ\n");

        //}

        //private void DoCapture()
        //{
        //    while (!bIsTimeToDie)
        //    {
        //        cbCapTmp = 2048;
        //        int ret = zkfp2.AcquireFingerprint(mDevHandle, FPBuffer, CapTmp, ref cbCapTmp);
        //        if (ret == zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK)
        //        {
        //            SendMessage(FormHandle, MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        //        }
        //        Thread.Sleep(200);
        //    }
        //}

        //protected override void DefWndProc(ref Message m)
        //{
        //    switch (m.Msg)
        //    {
        //        case MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK:
        //            {
        //                picFPImg = new PictureBox();
        //                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        //                BitmapFormat.GetBitmap(FPBuffer, mfpWidth, mfpHeight, ref ms);
        //                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
        //                this.picFPImg.Image = bmp;


        //                String strShow = zkfp2.BlobToBase64(CapTmp, cbCapTmp);
        //                textRes.AppendText("capture template data:" + strShow + "\n");

        //                if (IsRegister)
        //                {
        //                    int ret = zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK;
        //                    int fid = 0, score = 0;
        //                    ret = zkfp2.DBIdentify(mDBHandle, CapTmp, ref fid, ref score);
        //                    if (zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK == ret)
        //                    {
        //                        textRes.AppendText("This finger was already register by " + fid + "!\n");
        //                        return;
        //                    }

        //                    if (RegisterCount > 0 && zkfp2.DBMatch(mDBHandle, CapTmp, RegTmps[RegisterCount - 1]) <= 0)
        //                    {
        //                        textRes.AppendText("Please press the same finger 3 times for the enrollment.\n");
        //                        return;
        //                    }

        //                    Array.Copy(CapTmp, RegTmps[RegisterCount], cbCapTmp);
        //                    String strBase64 = zkfp2.BlobToBase64(CapTmp, cbCapTmp);
        //                    byte[] blob = zkfp2.Base64ToBlob(strBase64);
        //                    RegisterCount++;
        //                    if (RegisterCount >= REGISTER_FINGER_COUNT)
        //                    {
        //                        RegisterCount = 0;
        //                        if (zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK == (ret = zkfp2.DBMerge(mDBHandle, RegTmps[0], RegTmps[1], RegTmps[2], RegTmp, ref cbRegTmp)) &&
        //                               zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK == (ret = zkfp2.DBAdd(mDBHandle, iFid, RegTmp)))
        //                        {
        //                            iFid++;
        //                            textRes.AppendText("enroll succ\n");
        //                        }
        //                        else
        //                        {
        //                            textRes.AppendText("enroll fail, error code=" + ret + "\n");
        //                        }
        //                        IsRegister = false;
        //                        return;
        //                    }
        //                    else
        //                    {
        //                        textRes.AppendText("You need to press the " + (REGISTER_FINGER_COUNT - RegisterCount) + " times fingerprint\n");
        //                    }
        //                }
        //                else
        //                {
        //                    if (cbRegTmp <= 0)
        //                    {
        //                        textRes.AppendText("Please register your finger first!\n");
        //                        return;
        //                    }
        //                    if (bIdentify)
        //                    {
        //                        int ret = zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK;
        //                        int fid = 0, score = 0;
        //                        ret = zkfp2.DBIdentify(mDBHandle, CapTmp, ref fid, ref score);
        //                        if (zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK == ret)
        //                        {
        //                            textRes.AppendText("Identify succ, fid= " + fid + ",score=" + score + "!\n");
        //                            return;
        //                        }
        //                        else
        //                        {
        //                            textRes.AppendText("Identify fail, ret= " + ret + "\n");
        //                            return;
        //                        }
        //                    }
        //                    else
        //                    {
        //                        int ret = zkfp2.DBMatch(mDBHandle, CapTmp, RegTmp);
        //                        if (0 < ret)
        //                        {
        //                            textRes.AppendText("Match finger succ, score=" + ret + "!\n");
        //                            return;
        //                        }
        //                        else
        //                        {
        //                            textRes.AppendText("Match finger fail, ret= " + ret + "\n");
        //                            return;
        //                        }
        //                    }
        //                }
        //            }
        //            break;

        //        default:
        //            base.DefWndProc(ref m);
        //            break;
        //    }
        //}


        //private void identify()
        //{
        //    if (!bIdentify)
        //    {
        //        bIdentify = true;
        //        textRes.AppendText("Please press your finger!\n");
        //    }
        //}

        //private void verify()
        //{
        //    if (bIdentify)
        //    {
        //        bIdentify = false;
        //        textRes.AppendText("Please press your finger!\n");
        //    }
        //}

        //private void mach()
        //{
        //    txtTemplate1 = new TextBox();
        //    txtTemplate2 = new TextBox();
        //    txtTemplate1.Text = "text";
        //    txtTemplate2.Text = "text";
        //    byte[] blob1 = Convert.FromBase64String(txtTemplate1.Text.Trim());
        //    byte[] blob2 = Convert.FromBase64String(txtTemplate2.Text.Trim());

        //    int ret = zkfp2.DBMatch(mDBHandle, blob1, blob2);
        //    textRes.AppendText("Match template 1 vs template 2 score=" + ret + "!\n");
        //}




        #endregion
    }
}
```

Вот так я выношу:

```
namespace ReadAndVerify
{
    public partial class zkt : Form
    {

        public ComboBox cmbIdx;
        public TextBox textRes;
        public PictureBox picFPImg;
        public TextBox txtTemplate1;
        public TextBox txtTemplate2;


        IntPtr mDevHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr mDBHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr FormHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool bIsTimeToDie = false;
        bool IsRegister = false;
        bool bIdentify = true;
        byte[] FPBuffer;
        int RegisterCount = 0;
        const int REGISTER_FINGER_COUNT = 3;

        byte[][] RegTmps = new byte[3][];
        byte[] RegTmp = new byte[2048];
        byte[] CapTmp = new byte[2048];

        int cbCapTmp = 2048;
        int cbRegTmp = 0;
        int iFid = 1;

        private int mfpWidth = 0;
        private int mfpHeight = 0;
        private int mfpDpi = 0;

        const int MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK = 0x0400 + 6;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public zkt(IntPtr FormHandle)
        {
            this.FormHandle = FormHandle;
        }

        public void init()
        {
            cmbIdx = new ComboBox();
            cmbIdx.Items.Clear();
            int ret = zkfperrdef.ZKFP_ERR_OK;
            if ((ret = zkfp2.Init()) == zkfperrdef.ZKFP_ERR_OK)
            {
                int nCount = zkfp2.GetDeviceCount();
                if (nCount > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++)
                    {
                        cmbIdx.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                    }
                    cmbIdx.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    zkfp2.Terminate();
                    MessageBox.Show("No device connected!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Initialize fail, ret=" + ret + " !");
            }
        }

        public void free()
        {
            zkfp2.Terminate();
            cbRegTmp = 0;
        }

        public void open()
        {
            textRes = new TextBox();
            int ret = zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK;
            if (IntPtr.Zero == (mDevHandle = zkfp2.OpenDevice(cmbIdx.SelectedIndex)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OpenDevice fail");
                return;
            }
            if (IntPtr.Zero == (mDBHandle = zkfp2.DBInit()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Init DB fail");
                zkfp2.CloseDevice(mDevHandle);
                mDevHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                return;
            }
            RegisterCount = 0;
            cbRegTmp = 0;
            iFid = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                RegTmps[i] = new byte[2048];
            }
            byte[] paramValue = new byte[4];
            int size = 4;
            zkfp2.GetParameters(mDevHandle, 1, paramValue, ref size);
            zkfp2.ByteArray2Int(paramValue, ref mfpWidth);

            size = 4;
            zkfp2.GetParameters(mDevHandle, 2, paramValue, ref size);
            zkfp2.ByteArray2Int(paramValue, ref mfpHeight);

            FPBuffer = new byte[mfpWidth * mfpHeight];

            size = 4;
            zkfp2.GetParameters(mDevHandle, 3, paramValue, ref size);
            zkfp2.ByteArray2Int(paramValue, ref mfpDpi);

            textRes.AppendText("reader parameter, image width:" + mfpWidth + ", height:" + mfpHeight + ", dpi:" + mfpDpi + "\n");

            Thread captureThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoCapture));
            captureThread.IsBackground = true;
            captureThread.Start();
            bIsTimeToDie = false;
            textRes.AppendText("Open succ\n");

        }

        public void DoCapture()
        {
            while (!bIsTimeToDie)
            {
                cbCapTmp = 2048;
                int ret = zkfp2.AcquireFingerprint(mDevHandle, FPBuffer, CapTmp, ref cbCapTmp);
                if (ret == zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK)
                {
                    SendMessage(FormHandle, MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }

        protected override void DefWndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK:
                    {
                        picFPImg = new PictureBox();
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        BitmapFormat.GetBitmap(FPBuffer, mfpWidth, mfpHeight, ref ms);
                        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
                        this.picFPImg.Image = bmp;


                        String strShow = zkfp2.BlobToBase64(CapTmp, cbCapTmp);
                        textRes.AppendText("capture template data:" + strShow + "\n");

                        if (IsRegister)
                        {
                            int ret = zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK;
                            int fid = 0, score = 0;
                            ret = zkfp2.DBIdentify(mDBHandle, CapTmp, ref fid, ref score);
                            if (zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK == ret)
                            {
                                textRes.AppendText("This finger was already register by " + fid + "!\n");
                                return;
                            }

                            if (RegisterCount > 0 && zkfp2.DBMatch(mDBHandle, CapTmp, RegTmps[RegisterCount - 1]) <= 0)
                            {
                                textRes.AppendText("Please press the same finger 3 times for the enrollment.\n");
                                return;
                            }

                            Array.Copy(CapTmp, RegTmps[RegisterCount], cbCapTmp);
                            String strBase64 = zkfp2.BlobToBase64(CapTmp, cbCapTmp);
                            byte[] blob = zkfp2.Base64ToBlob(strBase64);
                            RegisterCount++;
                            if (RegisterCount >= REGISTER_FINGER_COUNT)
                            {
                                RegisterCount = 0;
                                if (zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK == (ret = zkfp2.DBMerge(mDBHandle, RegTmps[0], RegTmps[1], RegTmps[2], RegTmp, ref cbRegTmp)) &&
                                       zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK == (ret = zkfp2.DBAdd(mDBHandle, iFid, RegTmp)))
                                {
                                    iFid++;
                                    textRes.AppendText("enroll succ\n");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    textRes.AppendText("enroll fail, error code=" + ret + "\n");
                                }
                                IsRegister = false;
                                return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                textRes.AppendText("You need to press the " + (REGISTER_FINGER_COUNT - RegisterCount) + " times fingerprint\n");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (cbRegTmp <= 0)
                            {
                                textRes.AppendText("Please register your finger first!\n");
                                return;
                            }
                            if (bIdentify)
                            {
                                int ret = zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK;
                                int fid = 0, score = 0;
                                ret = zkfp2.DBIdentify(mDBHandle, CapTmp, ref fid, ref score);
                                if (zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK == ret)
                                {
                                    textRes.AppendText("Identify succ, fid= " + fid + ",score=" + score + "!\n");
                                    return;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    textRes.AppendText("Identify fail, ret= " + ret + "\n");
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                int ret = zkfp2.DBMatch(mDBHandle, CapTmp, RegTmp);
                                if (0 < ret)
                                {
                                    textRes.AppendText("Match finger succ, score=" + ret + "!\n");
                                    return;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    textRes.AppendText("Match finger fail, ret= " + ret + "\n");
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    base.DefWndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void identify()
        {
            if (!bIdentify)
            {
                bIdentify = true;
                textRes.AppendText("Please press your finger!\n");
            }
        }

        public void verify()
        {
            if (bIdentify)
            {
                bIdentify = false;
                textRes.AppendText("Please press your finger!\n");
            }
        }

        public void mach()
        {
            txtTemplate1 = new TextBox();
            txtTemplate2 = new TextBox();
            txtTemplate1.Text = "text";
            txtTemplate2.Text = "text";
            byte[] blob1 = Convert.FromBase64String(txtTemplate1.Text.Trim());
            byte[] blob2 = Convert.FromBase64String(txtTemplate2.Text.Trim());

            int ret = zkfp2.DBMatch(mDBHandle, blob1, blob2);
            textRes.AppendText("Match template 1 vs template 2 score=" + ret + "!\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Теперь я могу в любом классе написать:

```
zkt _zkt = new zkt(this.Handle);
_zkt.init();
_zkt.open();
```

> Но как сдесь же переопределить метод?? копи паст?? или можно как то вызвать??

Comment: может это все на код ревью перенести и там уже рассматривать, вам нужно внести множество правок, а это не оверфлошный вопрос!

Comment: [c# на код ревью](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23)

Comment: Либо, по каждому методу задавать конкретный вопрос, как его изменить.

Comment: Ну и что-бы окончательно быть правильным, посмотрите на ваш код через призму SOLID принципов программирования. Я бы ваш код разделил, как минимум на две части: Бизнес логика и отрисовка форм. Это даст возможность править безбоязнено код и тестировать его, и значительно упростит разработку.

Comment: @VladimirT вопрос стоял о конкретном методе.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Если о конкретном методе, так и приведите МСВП для этого метода, зачем простыни кода нам показывать?

Comment: @Anamnian затем, что бы было понятно, зачем я это делаю, тем более, что именно этот метод большенство метса и занимает. `DefWndProc`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Зачем вам свитч на 2 кейса? почему не проверять `m.Msg != MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK` и сразу вызывать метод базового класса, иначе выполнять остальной код?

Comment: @Anamnian возможно дополнение другими кейсами. Просто "пока" обхожусь одним.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц если будет такая же логика (вызов метода базового класса при неудовлетворении заданных условий) сохранятся в другом классе-  тогда следует наследоваться от класса `zkt`.

Comment: @Anamnian т е если я унаследую скжем в `Autoriz:zkt` , то у меня в нем переопределится метод `DefWndProc` и класс `Form` будет доступен через класс `zkt`,  верно я понял?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наследуйтесь от `zkt`, чтобы иметь возможность вызвать его через `base` в методе переопределения:

```
public class a
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}
public class b : a
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        base.DoSomething(); //void a.Something
    }
}
public class c : b
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        base.DoSomething(); //void b.Something
    }
}
```

---

Вы также можете запретить наследование, использовав модификатор `sealed`:

```
public class a
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {

    }

}
public class b : a
{
    public override sealed void DoSomething()
    {
        base.DoSomething();
    }
}
public class c : b
{
    // ERROR: 'c.DoSomething()': cannot override inherited member 'b.DoSomething()'
    // because it is sealed
    public override void DoSomething() 
    {
        base.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое